# Makefile: compile source, header, shared library files into an output directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

**I'm new to makefiles**

There's a ton of options to explore. I have just tried simple makefiles involving compiling a `.c` file and its corresponding `.h` file on the same location but I have this problem of compiling a large project just to observe its output of some sort.

The structure is this:

For project 1:

```
/maindirectory/project1/include/.h files
/maindirectory/project1/source/.c files
/maindirectory/project1/sharedlibrary/.so files
```

For project 2:

```
/maindirectory/project2/include/.h files
/maindirectory/project2/source/.c files
/maindirectory/project2/sharedlibrary/ .so files
```

Now there is a "test" `.c` file that is somehow tests the functionality of some code declared in those projects.

Now I know this test file should lie in `/maindirectory/test.c` along with the whole project directories of 1 and 2 and create a `makefile` to build all the necessary dependencies.

The `test.c` file `#include`s some source `.c` files in project 1 and project 2 while it also references a `.h` file in project 2. I also noticed it throws some "undefined reference to a `<function_name>`" and this function name has no implementation on the `.h` file, so I assume its implementation belongs to a shared library file.

I need help/guidance/light on how I could combine all of them through a `makefile` without exploring tons of files with thousands of lines just to know the whole structure?

Comment: Including c files doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain why you include a c file?

Comment: @nitzanms: Yes, it is uncommon to include `.c` files, whether it makes sense (or not) is a different story and, I'd say, depends on the specify needs.

Comment: Which is why I'm asking about it.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] how I could combine all of them through a `makefile` without exploring tons of files with thousands of lines just to know the whole structure?

gcc (or more accurate its pre-processor) provides the `-M` option to list dependencies.

From [gcc's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -M
>
> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for `make` describing the dependencies of the main source file. The preprocessor outputs one `make` rule containing the object file name for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, including those coming from `-include` or `-imacros` command-line options.

Comment: @user3115201: This gives you the dependencies necessary to compiles the sources, not to link them.